# How to create own functions using jQuery and call it in another functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have piece of function which I am trying to call at two different places and so am thinking to put it inside a function and call that function at two different places.

I am not sure how this can be done using jQuery:

Any Sample examples would be appreciated ?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Redundant code is 100 lines and so not willing to post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to worry about jQuery - just define your function :

```
function myFunction() {
  ...
}
```

and then call it wherever you like :

```
myFunction();
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I am getting some wierd errors messages

Comment: if I do call using `myFunction: function()` and then call using `this.myFunction()` than it works fine, what is the difference between two ways of calling a function ?

Comment: `myFunction: function()` what do you mean by that? are you defining the function on an object? the simple syntax i gave in my answer is just for a global function that can be called from anywhere.

Comment: Yes. I am defining function on a object, also is that the best practice of doing it or not ?

Comment: yeah that's certainly a good practice for object-oriented coding. the only caveat is if it means you have to pass loads of references to the object around, it might be easier to make it a normal, global, function.